# Line Chart in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am drawing the line chart in crystal report.I want to have different data sources for both X-axis and Y-axis.Both Data sources are .Net objects.
I am able to get the points both on X-axis and Y-axis but the graph is not getting plot. Calculations along Y-axis depends on the point on X-axis.

I have attached the screenshot of the same[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmMic.png)

Comment: can you provide the structure of your data? and what fields are you showing in X and Y? and a sample of your data as well

Comment: Along X-axis,I am displaying Acuity Levels:They are stored in DB as follows:Acuity Level(1,2,3 etc..),Range(2-3,3-4,4-5 etc..)                     Along Y-axis,I am calculating the % of assessments corresponding to each acuity level.The Assessments are stored in the DB as follows:                  Assessment(1,2,3,  etc..) , AcuityLevel(1,2,3  etc...)